# Getting values from XML type field using in SQL server

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2005, t-sql, xquery

I have  MS SQL table which contains a XML type field. This field has data in the format below:

```
<doc>
   <quote>
      <code>AA</code>
   </quote>
   <quote>
      <code>BB</code>
   </quote>
   <quote>
      <code>CC</code>
   </quote>
</doc>
```

The quotes can be in different orders. I need to see the data in the below format which shows which quote came first second and third for each document.

```
Code 1       Code 2        Code 3
--------------------------------
   AA         BB          CC
   BB         AA          CC
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @test TABLE(ID INT, XmlCol XML)

INSERT INTO @test VALUES(1, '<doc>
   <quote>
      <code>AA</code>
   </quote>
   <quote>
      <code>BB</code>
   </quote>
   <quote>
      <code>CC</code>
   </quote>
</doc>')

INSERT INTO @test VALUES(2, '<doc>
   <quote>
      <code>BB</code>
   </quote>
   <quote>
      <code>AA</code>
   </quote>
   <quote>
      <code>CC</code>
   </quote>
</doc>')

SELECT
    ID,
    X.Doc.value('(quote/code)[1]', 'varchar(20)') AS 'Code1',
    X.Doc.value('(quote/code)[2]', 'varchar(20)') AS 'Code2',
    X.Doc.value('(quote/code)[3]', 'varchar(20)') AS 'Code3'
FROM @test
CROSS APPLY xmlcol.nodes('doc') AS X(Doc)
```

Gives you an output of:

```
ID  Code1   Code2   Code3
1   AA  BB  CC
2   BB  AA  CC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
declare @x xml = '<doc>
   <quote>
      <code>AA</code>
   </quote>
   <quote>
      <code>BB</code>
   </quote>
   <quote>
      <code>CC</code>
   </quote>
</doc>';

select @x.value('(doc/quote/code)[1]', 'varchar(max)')
    , @x.value('(doc/quote/code)[2]', 'varchar(max)')
    , @x.value('(doc/quote/code)[3]', 'varchar(max)')
```

For @marc_s,

```
DECLARE @test TABLE(ID INT, XmlCol XML)

INSERT INTO @test VALUES(1, '<doc>
   <quote>
      <code>AA</code>
   </quote>
   <quote>
      <code>BB</code>
   </quote>
   <quote>
      <code>CC</code>
   </quote>
</doc>')

INSERT INTO @test VALUES(2, '<doc>
   <quote>
      <code>BB</code>
   </quote>
   <quote>
      <code>AA</code>
   </quote>
   <quote>
      <code>CC</code>
   </quote>
</doc>')




SELECT
    ID,
    XmlCol.value('(doc/quote/code)[1]', 'varchar(20)') AS 'Code1',
    XmlCol.value('(doc/quote/code)[2]', 'varchar(20)') AS 'Code2',
    XmlCol.value('(doc/quote/code)[3]', 'varchar(20)') AS 'Code3'
FROM @test
```

Comment: OK, in this case, when you have a single `<doc>` node in your XML column - yes it works.